# How do I stop getting notifications from this stack exchange?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, notifications

I'll spare you all the rant but I don't like this stack exchange anymore and haven't for several years. The obvious solution was to stop reading it.

But I do use other stack exchanges. And sometimes I get notifications from RPG. Usually they're just points for getting upvotes on something I wrote years ago. Sometimes they're pretty negative. I'd rather not get them at all. Is there any way to do this short of deleting all the content I ever posted?  If that's the only way, is there a bulk delete option?

(Yes, I tried google but only got answers about programming notifications in a variety of systems.)

Comment: Might be better to ask this on Stackoverflow meta as a general feature issue.

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith Not Stackoverflow meta, that's only for SO. There's a dedicated meta.SE now that's for the whole network.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie good looking out.

Comment: @DavidWilkins This is about the top-bar notifications, not email.

Answer (score 8):

This is an issue about the SE network rather than RPG.SE specifically, and has been asked here: [Is there a way to disable all forms of notification for a specific site? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179434/is-there-a-way-to-disable-all-forms-of-notification-for-a-specific-site). The long and short of it is: no, not without asking for your RPG.SE account to be deleted.

There are at least two (slightly different) feature requests on Meta.SE to allow muting or disabling notifications, which you may want to vote up:

- [Don't show me notifications or comments from sites I'm logged out of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157405/dont-show-me-notifications-or-comments-from-sites-im-logged-out-of)
- [More control over multicollider](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132922/more-control-over-multicollider)

Answer (score 5):

@sevensideddie's links told me there was no such feature in stackexchange.  I did the next best thing I could think of which was write a userstyle that hides those links so I don't have to look at them anymore.  https://userstyles.org/styles/110509/stack-exchange-notification-hider

Comment: Nice solution. You might consider posting it as a comment (or even answer) to one or more of those Meta.SE links. This is a script I will probably find useful at times, and I bet others would too.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to do this short of deleting all the content I ever posted? If that's the only way, is there a bulk delete option?

There's a slightly less nuclear option that leaves your content intact: you can delete your RPG.SE account. [The guidance on doing that is here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/152515). Your posts will become dissociated from your account, since you'll no longer have one here. As for the votes you've cast, since you're a high reputation user with lots of voting history, [the Community♦ user will take ownership of those votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286156/254830) (in other cases they'd just disappear).

If you want your posts to no longer display your name beneath them after account deletion, you should change your name on here prior to account deletion.

This won't blow up every account you have on every network site, just the sites where you request it.

Comment: [Dissociating accounts is not longer supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109044/how-can-i-disassociate-an-account), due to account/network architecture changes that make dissociation no different from normal per-site account deletion.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie thanks, edited